# Newbie VM O/S - Best Practices

Tags: operating-system, virtual-machine

I have digital mixer that runs a proprietary DOS/UNIX like O/S. I would like to setup a VM environment for the O/S in hope that I can provide enhancement via some sort of wrapper or API. What are things I should consider in trying to setup such environment. The feedback below is from one of the developers:

> The problem is that the OS is very particular about which hardware is
>   connected.For my experiments, the OS stopped booting when it tried to
>   activate `write combining` for the graphics card. And I didn´t find
>   any way to make the virtual machine emulate that. I tried to see if I
>   could make the VM emulate one of the ati cards that seems to work for
>   these machines - also without luck.